# Facebook API - Ad Videos Chunked Upload Sizes and API Limits

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, chunked

I'm using the chunked upload methods for ad videos in Facebook, referenced here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/advideo/v4.0#chunked

It looks like no matter what the size of the video is, the response always comes back indicating to chunk the video by 1MB. This is going off the `end_offset`. So a 700MB video would turn into 700 chunks and 700 API calls.

Does anyone know if there's a way to change the chunk size? And would each of these calls count towards the API limit?